# Linq: how i get the value of an object

Tags: c#, linq, jira-rest-api

**Problem:**

I try to map all issues of updated worklogs from date "x". The jira API supports only 1000 elements:
[Jira API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.1/#api/2/worklog-getIdsOfWorklogsModifiedSince)

Now I would like to get the value of the last `x.Until`

[Debugger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xO6a.png)

But the value ist still: `` "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[TempusDraft.tmpUpdatedWorklog,System.UInt64]" ``

Dafuq? Why? I can't see my mistake.

And how i get the correct value (look image)?

Thanks a lot and stay healty!

**Classes:**

```
class tmpUpdatedWorklog
{  
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    public List<worklog> Values { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("since")]
    public ulong Since { get; set; }
        
    [JsonPropertyName("until")]
    public ulong Until { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("lastPage")]
    public bool LastPage { get; set; }

    public class worklog
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("worklogId")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("updatedTime")]
        public long updatedTime { get; set; }
    }
}

class tmpWorklogRequestModel
{
        [JsonPropertyName("ids")]
        public List<long> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

**Methods:**

```
private static async Task<List<tmpUpdatedWorklog>> GetUpdatedWorklogs(HttpClient client, List<tmpUpdatedWorklog> tmpUpdatedWorklogs)
        {
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync($"{JIRA_BASE_URL}worklog/updated?since={DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(-2).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}");
            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<tmpUpdatedWorklog>(stream);
            tmpUpdatedWorklogs.Add(result);
            return tmpUpdatedWorklogs;
        }

private static async Task<List<tmpUpdatedWorklog>> GetUpdatedWorklogs(HttpClient client, List<tmpUpdatedWorklog> tmpUpdatedWorklogs, string since)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(since.ToString());
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync($"{JIRA_BASE_URL}worklog/updated?since={since}");
            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<tmpUpdatedWorklog>(stream);
            tmpUpdatedWorklogs.Add(result);
            return tmpUpdatedWorklogs;
        }
```

**Using:**

```
// other stuff before

private static readonly string JIRA_BASE_URL = "[link]";

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // other stuff before
        List<tmpUpdatedWorklog> tmpUpdatedWorklogs = new List<tmpUpdatedWorklog>();
        var results = await GetUpdatedWorklogs(client, tmpUpdatedWorklogs);
                
        while (!results.Select(x => x.LastPage).Contains(true)) 
        {
             // this doesn't work:
             // looks like: {JIRA_BASE_URL}worklog/updated?since=System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[TempusDraft.tmpUpdatedWorklog,System.UInt64]
             results = await GetUpdatedWorklogs(client, tmpUpdatedWorklogs, results.Select(x => x.Until).ToString());
        }
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling ToString() on the IEnumerable returned by the Select-statement. If I understand the logic of your application correctly (I don't know the Jira API), you should replace

```
while (!results.Select(x => x.LastPage).Contains(true)) 
{
         // this doesn't work:
         // looks like: {JIRA_BASE_URL}worklog/updated?since=System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[TempusDraft.tmpUpdatedWorklog,System.UInt64]
         results = await GetUpdatedWorklogs(client, tmpUpdatedWorklogs, results.Select(x => x.Until).ToString());
}
```

with something like

```
while (!results.Select(x => x.LastPage).Contains(true)) 
{
         // this doesn't work:
         // looks like: {JIRA_BASE_URL}worklog/updated?since=System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[TempusDraft.tmpUpdatedWorklog,System.UInt64]
         results = await GetUpdatedWorklogs(client, tmpUpdatedWorklogs, results.Select(x => x.Until).Last().ToString());
}
```

(The only difference is the Last-statement at the end.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3